# How to select java version for pyjnius

Tags: java, python-2.7, pyjnius

I have `Java 1.6.0_17` installed in `/usr/local/bin`.
My `Java` program is compiled with `1.7.0_11`.

`pyjnius` fails in a call   `X = autoclass('HelloWorld')`

When `HelloWorld.java` is compiled with `1.6`, everything works.

I cannot get `pyjnius` working with `1.7`.

I've tried setting `JAVA_HOME` before importing `jnius`:

```
import os
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = '/usr/local/pkgs/jdk-1.7.0.11'
from jnius import autoclass
XX = autoclass('HelloWorld')
```

I've also set `JAVA_HOME` in `.bash_profile` and added `/usr/local/pkgs/jdk-1.7.0.11/bin` the first in my `PATH`.

Comment: Try rerunning 'sudo python setup.py install' to configure pyjnius with the new java environment.

Comment: This is it.  Thanks!  Please let me know how to mark your answer as a correct one.

Comment: Glad it worked. I posted my reply as an answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyjnius needs to be reinstalled in order to configure it with the new java environment. That can be done by running the following in the downloaded or cloned pyjnius GiHub project folder:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```